# VFD minimum speed (frequency) and speed reference signal mapping

Tags: vfd

I am new to VFD configuration. Suppose I am using VFD for a variable speed pump control. The VFD is programmed to have minimum frequency 30 Hz and maximum frequency 60 Hz.

The VFD receives its speed reference signal from a controller.
If the controller outputs 4.0~20.0 mA, can following cases be done?

Case1: 4.0mA maps to 30 Hz, 20.0 mA to 60 Hz

Case2: 12.0 mA maps 30 Hz, 20.0 mA to 60 Hz with VFD having low cut off at 30 Hz, i.e., when controller outputs 4.0~12.0 mA, VFD maintains 30 Hz

What is the drawback of the case 2 if it can be done?

In case that the controller output is a digital signal (real number 0.00~100.00) as VFD speed reference signal, what is the difference between the two cases

case 1 number 0.00 maps to 30 Hz and 100.00 maps to 60 Hz

case 2 number 50.00 maps to 30 Hz and 100.00 maps to 60 Hz

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand, I think you are asking if there is any advantage or disadvantage to these different mappings.

If your VFD uses current sensing as an input you get better resolution in case 1. Current sensing circuitry will have some resolution, for example it might be 1.0mA or 0.1mA. So if we assume your VFD has 0.1mA resolution in case 1 you get 160 control points and in case 2 you only get 80 control points. Also current sensing would be classified under analog signal, and analog signals are much prone to electrical noise. So in case 1 you would get better accuracy.

In digital signal scenario you are less likley to encounter noise problem and the only difference is resolution, here you resolution is defined by how many bits is used to represent your real number for example a 32 bit represenstion would give your better resolution than 16 bit representation. So similarly to analog current sensing scenario, you will get better accuracy in case 1 as you will have more control points.

Comment: Thanks Abhimanyu. In analog scenario, case 1 can achieve 0.625%/0.1mA speed resolution , case 2  can achieve 0.3125%/0.1mA speed resolution. It is quite easy to understand. In digital scenario, assuming 32-bit real number representation, what the exact difference between case 1 and case 2? Thanks

Comment: What metrics comparision are you asking about? Since we are talking about resolution I assume you want the difference in resolution. If so, there are various ways to represent a number in computer science. for example floating point representation or integeral representation. Since you say your VFD accepts real numbers it could be a single floating point number or 2 intergral numbers one integer representing the integer part and the other the decimal part. meaning if you real number is 123.456 one interger would be 123 and the other 456. In either case, case 1 will have double resolution.

Comment: You need to read the reference-manual/datasheet of your VFD for details on how to program you VFD. Different VFD's use different communication protocol(example register programming) and different communication buses(example MODBUS, CAN, EtherCAT) I cannot say for certain how your VFD is programmed.

Comment: Thanks @Bubu. I just looked into one of the PLC VFD digital communication settings. 0 represents 0% and 20,000 represents 100%. So the minimum speed is 0% and the resolution is 0.005%. If 100% speed represents 1000 rpm, the resolution is 0.05 rpm. If 0 represents 50% and 20,000 represents 100%, the minimum speed is 50% and the resolution is 0.0025%. If 100% speed represents 1000 rpm, the resolution is 0.025 rpm. Sounds right? Originally I thought the PLC and VFD communicate with float numbers.

Comment: Yes, this sounds about right!